# Change specific UICell backgroundcolor

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibackgroundcolor

I have a `UITableView` filled with stuff from a database.

Now I want to change the background color of only one cell, the one that is set 'active item'.

How can I find the cell with (as example) name = "Active Cell" and change the background color of that cell only.

Hope you guys understand, don't know how to explain it.

Comment: How do you know that cell is active or not? is there any data associated with the cell or its based on cell touch event?

Comment: Do you mean by changing cell background on cell selection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know which is the active item as the table is loaded / reloaded you can use...

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (!cell)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

       // permanent cell styling in here.

   }

    // non-permanent cell styling in here.

    // example
    MYCustomDataObject *object = [myDataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 

    cell.textlabel.text = object.text;

    BOOL isActive = [object.text isEqualToString:@"Active Cell"];
    cell.backgroundColor = isActive ? [UIColor redColor]:[UIColor clearColor];

    return cell;
}
```

If you need to access it at another time... say you've just set a new active item... you should call `[myTableView reloadData];` when the active item changes also.

Answer (score 0):

Example code below;

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tblView cellForRowAtIndex:index];//desired cell index and this could be get whenever you have data
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];//desired color
```

Comment: cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];